# PayPal - Payment on hold

Tags: paypal

I have next scenario.

I have person A and person B. Person A wants to buy some item from person B via PayPal but he wants to first get that item then confirms the payment to the person B when he makes sure he got the item and that everything is ok with an item.

Is that possible via PayPal API?

Comment: So you mean like an escrow ?

Comment: I have never used escrow in my life so I can't confirm or decline your question. I just want to avoid unsatisfied users if something wrong hapoens like user A buy item1 and user B sends him item2 which is wrong. If payment goes instantly user A will be unsatisfied cause he didn't ordered item 2. All I want is to make initial payment be placed on hold until item 1 arrives to user A. After that user A would need to confirm that item he ordered arrived so the payment can go from on hold to the user B.

Comment: That’s why PayPal offers purchase protection- isn’t that sufficient ? The mechanism that you describe is what is typically known as escrow

Comment: Can you please describe that purchase protection or link the official documentation on that purchase protection? If my situation happens, wilk user A be able to get his money back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your describing is something that an "escrow" service would offer. i.e. hold the money till the buyer is happy with the purchase and then release it to the seller and if not happy manage the dispute. The seller has the guarantee that funds are secured and the buyer has a guarantee that it's not released prematurely. This is not available out of the box with PayPal but the way you can get around it is via

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-safety-and-security

Click on "i am a seller" and "i am a buyer" both sides of the equation are protected especially is such obvious cases that buyer ordered "A" and they got "B".